# Itertools in Julia

Tags: python, julia, python-itertools

I have array N-M dimension array -A. I need to generate the combinations of one element from each string and determine their sum.

Example,  A=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]. k=[1,3,5],[1,4,5],[1,4,6],[2,3,5],[2,3,6],[2,4,5],[2,4,6].

Thus k has three indexes for each combination. The summ=9, 10, 11, 10, 11, 11, 12.
Using python, I can do it with

```
sums = ((vs,sum(vs)) for vs in itertools.product(*A))
for k,v in sums:
    print v
    print k
```

How to do it using Julia?

Comment: To be clear, what you have there is not a multi-dimensional array. It's an array with arrays nested inside. The multi-dimensional array equivalent would be `A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]`

Answer (score 4):

```
julia> A=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]; vec([(sum(v), v) for v in Iterators.product(A...)])
8-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}}}:
 (9, (1, 3, 5))
 (10, (2, 3, 5))
 (10, (1, 4, 5))
 (11, (2, 4, 5))
 (10, (1, 3, 6))
 (11, (2, 3, 6))
 (11, (1, 4, 6))
 (12, (2, 4, 6))
```

seems pretty close.